# Yesod Persistent Examples

Tags: web-services, sqlite, haskell, yesod

I'm planing around with Yesod, and I am having trouble, I need a good example of how to take a form submission and enter it the SQLite persistent database. The [Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book) talks a lot about how to setup a table but is rather short on examples of how to insert a row and how to get a list of the data in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the source for the haskellers.com website is a great showcase of example code for yesod.

check it out.

[haskellers on github](https://github.com/snoyberg/haskellers)